# Jetty: how to secure websocket connection in web.xml?

Tags: websocket, jetty

I followed [this article](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websockets-an-introduction/) and created simplest websocket echo application. Although article is about Glassfish, I successfully run my app under Jetty 9, as they are using standard javax.websocket API in article.
It works just fine, but now I want to secure websocket connection. I googled around and found most examples are written as standalone Java application (with `public static void main()` method). They create new `ConnectionFactory` and starts server from their code (like [here](http://amilamanoj.blogspot.ru/2013/06/secure-websockets-with-jetty.html) for example).

But I want to run my app under Jetty as a container, so I want to just specify some options in web.xml or something, to secure my connection. So I found [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/securing_websocket_applications_on_glassfish) article and modified my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Protected resource</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <!-- https -->
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

The problem is it doesn't work. Probably because article is about Glassfish again.

How it is does NOT work:

- My IDE (IDEA) shows red all tags inside `<security-constraint>`, that means schema validation is failed and these tags can not be contained inside `<security-constraint>`
- When I try to open index.html over HTTPS I get error `ssl_error_rx_record_too_long` in browser and also there are two errors in Jetty output:

`Illegal character 0x16 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer`

and

`badMessage: 400 Illegal character 0x16 for HttpChannelOverHttp`

So.. What I am doing wrong? How to make secured websocket via Jetty or application configuration?

Comment: hi Andy, I'm seeing the exact same errors in the logs. were you able to resolve this? what did you change to make it work? thanks!

Comment: Hi, Hristo. Did you read article from the accepted answer below? https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL

Comment: yes, I've read it, Andy :) the only way I was able to resolve these errors was by removing the `http` module (commenting it out in `start.ini`). what did you do?

Comment: Actually now I can not remember exactly, but I uploaded working project for you on GitHub, so you may see yourself how it's done. Hope this will help! https://github.com/andrrey/wss-web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security constraint tag you described is mostly used for specify BASIC authentication mode in application server.

I guess you want to enable HTTPS and not authentication. For enabling HTTPS you may follow this article: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this HOWTO. It is not 100% complete and lacks some details about Jetty configuration, but it is a good point to start with. Starting from it I was finally able run Jetty in desired configuration.